# How can I add heterogeneous data to Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to add heterogenous data (i.e. of different "types") to Elasticsearch.  Each (top-level) object contains a user's settings for an application.  A simplified example is:

```
{
'name':'test',
'settings': [
    {
        'key':'color',
        'value':'blue'
    },
    {
        'key':'isTestingMode',
        'value':true
    },
    {
        'visibleColumns',
        'value': [
            'column1',
            'column3',
            'column4',
        ]
    },
    ...
    ...
}
```

When I try to add this, the POST fails with an MapperParsingException.  Searching around, it seems like this is because the 'value' field has different types.

Is there any way to just store arbitrary data like this?

Comment: Do you already have a mapping for that index. Meaning something that's pre-determined?

Comment: No, no mapping.  Up until when I started trying to insert data like this, everything just worked (I was under the impression that ES would somehow infer a mapping from the structure of the data).  Is there a way that I can do what I want by manually adding a mapping?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.
Mapping is per field and mapping is not array aware.
This means that you can keep settings.value as string or array but not both.

An easy tweak would be to define all value as array -

```
{
'name':'test',
'settings': [
    {
        'key':'color',
        'value': [ 'blue' ]
    },
    {
        'key':'isTestingMode',
        'value': [ true ] 
    },
    {
        'visibleColumns',
        'value': [
            'column1',
            'column3',
            'column4',
        ]
    },
    ...
    ...
}
```

If that is not acceptable ,  then another idea would be to apply [source transform](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-transform.html)  which will do this normalization to the settings.value field before it is indexed. This way , the source is kept as it is AND you will get what you want.